# Why shouldn't commas be included in sql field names?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, field

People keep telling me that spaces shouldn't be included in column names. I was just wondering, why is that? It is an issue I am having with a few database tables I am creating for school. The field names include Preble and Darke.

Instead, they need to be "Preble County (OH)" and "Darke County (OH)". If they were row names, I would just create an ID # column, and natural join that with a table displaying names that I want them to be ("Darke County (OH)" instead of "Darke").

However, I have no idea how I can go about changing these names since they are my field names. Can anyone help me out? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to know *why* you shouldn't include commas (or spaces it seems) in field names or the `ALTER TABLE` syntax to remove the spaces?

Comment: For instance, why shouldn't a field name be `Darke County (OH)`?

Comment: Because having to use backquotes (or double quotes) around every column and table name just clutters up the query, making it harder to understand and type.

Comment: Okay, so is there any way I could natural join two tables, so when I print a column name, I can print `Darke County (OH)` instead of `Darke`?

Comment: Things like spaces and commas in table names create more work for you to do.  You have to do something to escape the non-standard characters every single time you reference the table in a query.  The same goes for using sql keywords as table names.  In some database engines, it is also true for datatypes.

Comment: Do you have a column named \`Darke County (OH)\`, or a value in a column \`Something\` containing "Darke County (OH)"?  If the former, you definitely need to normalize your database.

Comment: So, basically I am screwed then? I am using php to build a website, and instead of printing `Darke` on the page, I would like it if it printed `Darke County (OH)`.

Comment: In real applications, column and table names are something the end user will never see. So they can and should bear more programmer/computer friendly names. This is obviously not true for school projects, where you basically access the database output directly, as you wouldn't in real life.

Comment: I think you are confusing field names with data. The field (or column) name in this case seems like it could just be `county`.

Answer (score 4):

tldr; *Trying to included commas (or other special characters) generally indicates a fundamental flaw with the column name<sup>2</sup>.*

This is a *bad* database design. It is *bad* because it tries to encode *information* into a column name<sup>1</sup>. This is not the point of a column name! A column name is merely a friendly moniker for an element of a record/tuple - nothing more. Under Relational Algebra (RA), and thus SQL, it is the record/tuple that contains the information.

Besides just leading to a schema that is hard to deal with (extra quoting syntax) that requires hard-coding queries based on changing information (column names and multiplicity), it is also impossible to use with a number of RA techniques in a flexible manner. RA can only generally handle multiplicity across records - and, as discovered, this includes joins.

Instead, the schema should look similar to, say:

```
County    State   Other Columns
=======   =====   =============
Darke     OH      ..
Prebel    OH      ..
```

Where the Key is, say, `(State,County)` and "Other Columns" are dependent upon the key. Of course the model should be correctly normalized in relation to all the other information that is captured.

Note that there is no information stored in the column names presented above: the names are merely friendly monikers representing the information stored in each column.

---

<sup>1</sup> Now a [*PIVOT transformation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table), which is primarily for human output/display, can be performed as needed. This is were a column in the output table (not schema table!) is generated per set of record values. However, this is a secondary issue and should not affect the primary schema.

If using SQL Server, one could first UNPIVOT the information-filled column names, perform the join and then re-PIVOT (given a known set of column names). However, I have no idea how this would be done in MySQL - a messy dynamic query, perhaps. In any case, this is an approach I would avoid.

---

<sup>2</sup> While special characters are not allowed in *bare identifiers*, it is possible to use such names when used in *quoted identifiers* - e.g. `Vancouver, WA` or, with [ANSI quotes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes), "Vancouver, WA". However, keep reading the rest of this response which argues against using such identifiers.