# Select a column with commas and quotes inside it in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-4

Working on upgrading an old piece of code I have stumbled upon some horror of a database with strange column names that include commas and quote characters inside them. I cannot rename those columns due to other circumstances so I have to find a workaround.

Such columns look like

```
CREATE TABLE `file` (
    `id` int(12) NOT NULL,
    `number,street,city,sector` text,
    `client\'s_mobile` text
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The old PHP code, using obsolete *MySQL* functions, doesn't seem to have a problem using these columns by surrounding them with backticks (`).

Now, when using Codeigniter 4's models, things don't go that smooth anymore. When trying to get the `client\'s_mobile` column, I do this:

```
$fileModel = new \App\Models\FileModel();
$file = $fileModel->select('`client\'s_mobile`')->where('id', $id)->first();
```

and it works but when I do it with the ones using commas it does not:

```
$file = $fileModel->select('`number,street,city,sector`')->where('id', $id)->first();
```

I get an exception stating

> `Unknown column 'street' in 'field list'`

It reads the entire column like 4 columns because of the commas inside. **How, if possible, can I specify that this is just one column?**

Comment: I would change the column names.

Comment: I don't know if this will work, but try double-quotes instead of ticks: `'"number,street,city,sector"'`

Comment: *Working on upgrading an old piece* then upgrade from DB side too

Comment: In such a clowfiesta you may want to use `query()` function so you have your queries under control : https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#regular-queries

Comment: if you want to use backticks, then use them, separately for every column. Like  ``` $fileModel->select('`number`, `street`, `city`, `sector`')->where('id', $id)->first(); ````

Comment: prefer underscore for your column name instead of comma or apos

Comment: It is bad database design. Read this usefull answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18704659/12396302